# Delete ink annotations from slides after saving

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, annotations, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

During a presentation, it is possible to add ink annotations to a slide using:

1. `Ctrl-P` to get the pen option.
2. Writing some text on a slide.
3. When leaving the presentation, selecting **Keep** from the *"Want to keep your ink annotations?"* dialog.

My question is: how can you remove those annotations after? The only way I know is `Ctrl-Z` - which of course only works if you don't close PowerPoint.

It is easy to find ways to remove the annotations using previous versions on PowerPoint, but PowerPoint 365 does not appear to support it.

<sub>[Or is the only solution to use a macro?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/deleting-ink-markup-in-powerpoint-2016/fcb13de5-d69d-41d6-a355-3d93c1bc2e1f)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You have the option to **Hide/Delete the Ink** even after keeping them. You can do that from the Review tab.

[image: Hide/Delete Ink]

Comment: I do not have that option, only *Hide Ink*. I cannot even add it via *Customise Ribbon*.

Comment: Can you check out the following answer in the Microsoft Forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ink-tools-missing/ef16f36d-944f-4b2f-ba83-bd3b6785fed2?tab=AllReplies#tabs

Comment: I'm not using a Surface (it's a desktop) and the ink pen is working, only the Delete options are not present.

Comment: You mentioned you cannot add it via Customize Ribbon, did you check for "**Hide Ink Menu**" in the All commands?

Comment: Yeah, I've only got a *Hide Ink **Button*** under *All Commands*; not a *Menu*. :(

Comment: I selected the `Delete All Ink in Presentation` option, after which it deleted ONE annotation. Now that button is greyed out and the other annotations remain.